# folium tooltip : is it possible to show tooltip on a condition of a field

Tags: python, folium

I have a folium map which work just fine with geoJson and tooltip.

```
m = folium.Map(location=[0, 0], zoom_start=2)
tooltip=folium.GeoJson(gdf).add_to(m)
folium.GeoJsonTooltip(fields=['value', 'comment']).add_to(tooltip)
```

My question is : is it possible to show the comment only if it is not empty ?
that's mean in this case, I will only see the value.

the other case is value + comment